# Change how numbers are printed in psql

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, format, rounding, psql

**How can I set numeric display format in `psql`?**
I have **many** `character varying` and `double precision` columns in the `select` query. I can use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) or [`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) on each of the numeric columns, but with many columns this makes the code too repetitive.

Is there a shortcut? For example, are there any `psql` session settings, something like `\pset numeric '9.9EEEEE'` (I just made it up, don't try to use it). I could not quickly find such settings in the manual: [PostgreSQL: Documentation: psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

**Example:**

```
-- Got this:
=# select bar from (values (123456789), (0.123456789), (0.000000123456789)) table_foo (bar);
        bar        
-------------------
         123456789
       0.123456789
 0.000000123456789

-- I have to use this workaround:
=# select to_char(bar, '9.9EEEEE') as bar from (values (123456789), (0.123456789), (0.000000123456789)) table_foo (bar);
   bar    
----------
  1.2e+08
  1.2e-01
  1.2e-07

-- I want this:
-- set some session settings, and then magically:
=# select bar from (values (123456789), (0.123456789), (0.000000123456789)) table_foo (bar);
   bar    
----------
  1.2e+08
  1.2e-01
  1.2e-07
```

Comment: Data are formatted on server side. psql just print already formatted text

Comment: @PavelStehule Seems like `numericlocale` formats the numeric data client-side... As `format` and `columns` for all data types.

Comment: this is reformatting of already formatted number in text form. You can check function `format_numeric_locale(const char *my_str)` in source code file `print.c`.

Comment: According to *Adrian Klaver*, "There is no such setting in psql. The closest you can get is `numericlocale` which modifies the thousands separator." But I was hoping for an answer or a workaround here.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing what you want

Comment: No amount of offering rubber points will make this feature materialize. But you could write a patch for `psql` or pay somebody to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not other possibility to specify number of format then specification of numeric locale. Values are formatted on server side already, `psql` does formatting to final output format (table, html, csv), but the values are formatted, and `psql` doesn't try to do reformat (`numericlocale` is an exception). I remember long discussion about possibility to specify output format of boolean type, but still without actual results. `psql` has not strong functionality for generating rich reports. It should be fast, safe and robust interactive client. Although I would to have some stronger possibility in this area, the modern spreadsheets and reporting tools are for some tasks better.

Answer (score 4):

You could always define your own formatting function, but you'd have to be doing a lot of formatting on a lot of columns for this to be considered an improvement in readability. I wouldn't recommend it for your toy example but if your real queries have dozens of columns it might be neater.

```
sophia=> create function x(numeric) returns text language sql as $$ select to_char($1, '9.9EEEEE') $$;
CREATE FUNCTION
sophia=> select x(bar) from (values (123456789), (0.123456789), (0.000000123456789)) table_foo (bar);
    x     
----------
  1.2e+08
  1.2e-01
  1.2e-07
(3 rows)

sophia=>
```